# Combinatorics definition help

Tags: combinatorics

I am really trying to understand descent set permutations, but before that there are some things I want to make clear from this paper I am reading. That is:

http://emis.ams.org/journals/EJC/Volume_16/PDF/v16i1r32.pdf

**Defintion 1.1:** For $\sigma \in \zeta_n,$ let $\phi_{j,k}(\sigma) =\tau_1\cdots\tau_{j-1}k\tau_j\cdots\tau_n$ where:
$$\tau_i =
\begin{cases}
\sigma_i,  & \text{if $\sigma_i< k$} \\
\sigma_i+1, & \text{if $\sigma_i\ge k$}
\end{cases}$$

Similarly, $\psi_j(\sigma)=\tau_1\cdots\tau_{j-1}\tau_{j+1}\cdots\tau_n$ where:
$$\tau_i =
\begin{cases}
\sigma_i,  & \text{if $\sigma_i< \sigma_j$} \\
\sigma_i-1, & \text{if $\sigma_i> \sigma_j$}
\end{cases}$$

On page 3, **Definition 1.1**, could some one please explain how this definition works, because I do not get the explanation of what this $\phi_{j,k}(\sigma)$ and $\psi_j(\sigma)$ are supposed to do. A numerical example will be an excellent way for me to understand.

I would appreciate the help.

Comment: Please just state the definition instead of making people try to download and search through a pdf file.

Comment: Ok I will do that.

Comment: What's $\zeta_n$?

Comment: It does not state explicitly in the paper, but I am guessing its the permutation of size $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems straightforward from their description below. "Thus, $φ_{j,k}$ inserts the element k at position j, increasing elements larger than k by one
and shifting elements to the right of position j one step further to the right. The map $ψ_j$ removes the element at position j, decreasing larger elements by one and shifting those to its right one step left.

Take a permutation of length 10 ($\zeta_n$). Now, if you want to create a permutation of size 11, you can introduce a number from 1-11 somewhere. Say you want to permute 4 to 6 ($\phi_{4,6}$), you introduce 6 at the position of 4, and increase all the previous assignments greater than equal to 6 by 1. I.e. if 7  permuted to 6 earlier, it would now permute to 7.

Removal is similar.

Comment: Actually I still do not get this, for instance if we have the permutation $\sigma = \sigma_1...\sigma_5=12345$, then the $\phi_{2,3}(\sigma) = \tau_1 3 \tau_2\tau_3\tau_4\tau_5 = 132456.$ I do not understand what this means.

Comment: @Aurora Borealis. It means "insert $3$ in position $2$ in the permutation $12345$ then shift the numbers to the right of it one more step right to give $132345$ then increase every number equal to or greater than $3$ by $1$ to give $132456$", that's it. If you were to, for example, operate $\phi_{3,3}$ on $23451$ it would create a *fixed point* at position $3$ giving $\phi_{3,3}(23451)=243561$ which is a permutation on $[6]$. Using $\psi_3(243561)=23451$ we see that every map of this kind is a bijection.

Comment: @N.Shales Thank you !, now I think I am almost there to fully understanding it, except I have one final question from your post you kindly made earlier regarding the actual problem.